# Getting cell values from Telerik WinForms radGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I am trying to get the cell value from Telerik WinForms radGridView. Here is the most recent code I've tried:

```
private void radGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlObj = radGridView1.SelectedCells.ToString();

        SQL.sqlConnect(sqlObj);

    }
```

Doing so only returns the following value:

[image]

I have tired other methods like radGridView1.SelectedRows.ToString(); but it just returns a similar value. Any ideas?

Comment: It says _SelectedCellsCollection_ you need to add the indexer of the cell you want to read here

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the cell value in the CellDoubleClick event:

```
    void radGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Value);
        //or
        object cellValue = e.Row.Cells[e.Column.Name].Value;
    }
```

More information about accessing cells can be found in the [Telerik UI for WinForms](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-cells-accessing-cells.html) documentation